# Syntax error in dynamic sql server query with pivot clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error, pivot

```
 Chromosome Locus       Variant_A   Variant_B   Variant Strain_ID   Family  Parent1_Name    Parent1_Marker  Parent2_Name    Parent2_Marker  Line    Marker  Gid
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gm09        40907915    G           A           GA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      BB      2
Gm09        422384      G           A           GA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      4
Gm09        422720      A           G           AG      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      BB      5
Gm09        424439      C           A           CA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      7
Gm09        425375      G           T           GT      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          AA              PI507.681B*     BB              96      AA      9
Gm09        425581      T           C           TC      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      BB      10
Gm09        43921862    C           A           CA      DS11.46096  46      IA3023          BB              PI507.681B*     AA              96      AA      12
```

I've attached the image of my table. This table individual ids in `Strain_ID` and each Id has several markers in different loci. I want to `pivot` on Loci aggregating on Marker, so that I can have individual `strain_Ids` in rows and all the loci as columns.

This is the script I use on Sql server 2012 Management studio:

```
declare @cols varchar(Max) 
declare @cols1 varchar(Max)     

set @cols ='[' ;

select @cols += 'D.'+QUOTENAME (Locus) + ','
from(
    select distinct Locus from genotypeQA where Chromosome IN ('Gm01')
) as X 

set @cols= stuff(replace(@cols,'D.[','['),1,1,'')
print @cols

set @cols1 = SUBSTRING(@cols,1,LEN(@cols)-1)
print @cols1

select *  
from (
    select 
    genotypeQA.Strain_ID, 
    genotypeQA.Family,
    '+ @cols +',
    genotypeQA.Marker
from genotypeQA
where 
    genotypeQA.Family IN ('10') 
    AND genotypeQA.Chromosome IN ('Gm01')  
) as D

Pivot( 
MAX(Marker) 
For Locus IN ('+ @cols +')) as p
```

I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 31
Incorrect syntax near '+ @cols +'.



I expect the following format of output shown here with part of the table: 


| Strain     |           | Gm09_40907915 | Gm09_422384 | Gm09_422720 | Gm09_424439 |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant_A | G             | G           | A           | C           |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant_B | A             | A           | G           | A           |    |
| DS11.46096 | Variant   | GA            | GA          | AG          |        CA    |  |
```

+------------+-----------+---------------+-------------+-------------+----------

Comment: The table got smudged in the post...The first 2 lines are the column headers until header Marker

Comment: @wewesthemenace : How did you format the table into this specific format. I want to edit  the expected output table into that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :**

First of all you need to bring `Variant`, `Variant_A` and `Variant_B` values to single column and corresponding values column name in another column, ie, you have to `UNPIVOT`. I have used `CROSS APPLY` instead of `UNPIVOT` here.

Declare a variable to get column names for pivoted table

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + ChrLocus + ']', '[' + ChrLocus + ']')
               FROM    
               (
                     SELECT DISTINCT Chromosome+'_'+ CAST(Locus AS VARCHAR(10))ChrLocus 
                     FROM #TEMP
               ) PV 
               ORDER BY ChrLocus
```

Now pivot the result. I have written the logic inside the query

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = '-- This outer query forms your pivoted result
             SELECT * FROM 
             (
                -- Source data for pivoting
                SELECT DISTINCT Chromosome+''_''+ CAST(Locus AS VARCHAR(10))ChrLocus,Strain_ID,
                Variants,COLNAMES 
                FROM #TEMP 
                CROSS APPLY(VALUES (Variant_A,''Variant_A''),(Variant_B,''Variant_B''),(Variant,''Variant''))
                AS COLUMNNAMES(Variants,COLNAMES)
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 --Defines the values in each dynamic columns
                 MIN(Variants)
                 -- Get the names from the @cols variable to show as column
                 FOR ChrLocus IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p            
            ORDER BY Strain_ID;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/283485) to view result**

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But it still doesn't work...Any other ideas

Comment: Hi Sarath, I'm getting the same error as mentioned in the problem.

Comment: Can u add expected output to the question @Vishnu Ramasubramanian

Comment: My expected output table is fudged. It has one strain like DS11.46096 in a row and Loci like Gm09_40907915 and Gm09_422384 as separate columns with markers like GA and AG as values.

Comment: I have updated answer. Please check and feel free to ask for any changes. @Vishnu Ramasubramanian

Comment: I tried once, it didn't work. So I'm tweaking your suggested code a bit and trying now...

Comment: I get the following error when i run with #TEMP replaced with my table.Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. @Sarath

Comment: The query is working with a working sql fiddle for the table and desired output in the question. @Vishnu Ramasubramanian

Comment: I use Sql server..May be there is a difference in format.

Comment: I tried to fix the error. It looks like sql server requires a different format for sub query with pivot clause. So I've posted the question in a different section along with a modification of the code you suggested....

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the SQL into a variable and then use EXEC(@sqlCode) to execute the SQL Dynamically. eg. `DECLARE @mySql AS VARCHAR(MAX) = sql pivot query here`. Then call EXEC(@sqlCode) to generate the result. Like this:

```
 DECLARE @sqlCode AS VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @sqlCode = 'select *
    from (
    select genotypeQA.Strain_ID, genotypeQA.Family,'+ @cols + ' ,genotypeQA.Marker from genotypeQA where genotypeQA.Family IN ('10') AND genotypeQA.Chromosome IN ('Gm01')
    ) as D
    Pivot( MAX(Marker) For Locus IN ('+ @cols +')) as p'
EXEC (@sqlCode)
```

Comment: When you print @cols, is there a comma at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: Not because of that. You cannot use `@cols` in pivot source query and in where clause `.IN ('Gm01')..` will also fail